# SQL Server & C#: duplicate insert error from unique data

Tags: c#, duplicates, unique

I insert unique data into SQL Server, but it is inserted twice. It happens one or twice time a year. When I delete inserted data and run procedure again, it doesn't happen on same data again. What is the reason and how to avoid it?

I use a SQL Server stored procedure, where is many select, use sequence, insert is in cursor. In procedure there is begin and commit transaction around insert. Duplicate happens for more orders, but after insert data for one order, there is commit. Error happens in one minute and another batch of inserts few minutes later, is OK.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//using System.
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WindowsService
{
    class WindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer myTimer;
        bool _smyckaBezi;

        public WindowsService()
        {
            this.ServiceName = "Windows Service Jobs OSTRA SAP";
            this.EventLog.Log = "Application";

            // These Flags set whether or not to handle that specific
            //  type of event. Set to true if you need it, false otherwise.
            this.CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
            this.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
            this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
            this.CanShutdown = true;
            this.CanStop = true;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new WindowsService());
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
            myTimer = new Timer(5000); // Sets a 10 second interval
            myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);// Specifies The Event Handler
            myTimer.Enabled = true;                                    // Enables the control
            myTimer.AutoReset = true;                                  // makes it repeat
            myTimer.Start();
        }

        protected void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_smyckaBezi) return;
            _smyckaBezi = true;

            SqlConnection conn = null;
            string output = null;
            List<string> list = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                Config config = new Config();
                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
                conn = new SqlConnection(cs);

                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 procedure_name AS [procedure_name] FROM dbo.jobs_sap WHERE datediff(minute, next_execution, getdate())>=0 AND upper(procedure_name) IN (SELECT upper(s.name)+'.'+upper(o.name) FROM sys.objects o JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id=s.schema_id WHERE o.type='P') ORDER BY next_execution";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                // execute the command that returns a SqlDataReader
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                // display the results
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    output = reader["procedure_name"].ToString();
                    list.Add(output);
                }
                reader.Close();

                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
                {
                    string pname = list[i];

                    string sql = "UPDATE dbo.jobs_sap SET last_execution = next_execution WHERE execution_time is not null AND procedure_name= '" + pname + "';";
                    SqlCommand cmdu = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmdu.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    sql = "UPDATE dbo.jobs_sap SET next_execution = convert(datetime,CAST(getdate()+1 AS DATE)) + CAST(execution_time AS DATETIME) WHERE execution_time is not null AND procedure_name= '" + pname + "';";
                    cmdu = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmdu.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    string sql2 = "UPDATE dbo.jobs_sap SET last_execution = next_execution WHERE execute_every_min is not null AND procedure_name= '" + pname + "';";
                    SqlCommand cmdu2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, conn);
                    cmdu2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    sql2 = "UPDATE dbo.jobs_sap SET next_execution = dateadd(minute, execute_every_min,getdate()) WHERE execute_every_min is not null AND procedure_name= '" + pname + "';";
                    cmdu2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, conn);
                    cmdu2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    _smyckaBezi = false;

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(list[i], conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)// catch (InvalidCastException e)
            {
                writeToLogFileService(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    _smyckaBezi = false;
                }
            }
        } 

        public static void writeToLogFileService(string logMessage)
        {
            string str_LogMessage = string.Empty;
            string str_LogFile = "d:\\temp\\log_jobs_sap.txt";
            StreamWriter swLog;
            
            str_LogMessage = string.Format("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, logMessage);

            if (!File.Exists(str_LogFile))
            {
                 swLog = new StreamWriter(str_LogFile);
            }
            else
            {
                swLog = File.AppendText(str_LogFile);
            }

            swLog.WriteLine(str_LogMessage);
            swLog.WriteLine();

            swLog.Close();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
        }

        protected override void OnContinue()
        {
            base.OnContinue();
        }

        protected override void OnShutdown()
        {
            base.OnShutdown();
        }

        protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
        {

            base.OnCustomCommand(command);
        }

        protected override bool OnPowerEvent(PowerBroadcastStatus powerStatus)
        {
            return base.OnPowerEvent(powerStatus);
        }


        protected override void OnSessionChange(
                  SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
        {
            base.OnSessionChange(changeDescription);
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace WindowsService
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class WindowsServiceInstaller : Installer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Public Constructor for WindowsServiceInstaller.
        /// - Put all of your Initialization code here.
        /// </summary>
        public WindowsServiceInstaller()
        {
            ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller =
                               new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

            //# Service Account Information
            serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            serviceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
            serviceProcessInstaller.Password = null;

            //# Service Information
            serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "Windows Service Jobs OSTRA SAP";
            serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

            //# This must be identical to the WindowsService.ServiceBase name
            //# set in the constructor of WindowsService.cs
            serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "Windows Service Jobs OSTRA SAP";

            this.Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);
            this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a unique Primary Key/Index constraint, you should get an error instead of a duplicate record. Also, adding your stored procedure and table definition would help to identify the issue.  But I would add a unique primary key or index to the table to prevent duplicate records. That will help identify the issue, especially if you are calling the procedure from an application.

Comment: I use number from sequence and guid for primary key, both are different for duplicate rows. It seems that run again in cursor. Procedure has 1300 rows. It is called from WS C#. Maybe is problem there. We have problem, that procdures were called twice, but we thought that we managed it. Some rows are created exactly in same time 2021-03-22 05:20:57.860, mostly with little difference 2021-03-22 05:20:38.403 and 2021-03-22 05:20:38.430.

Comment: I added C# code, table: 


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[jobs_sap](
 [procedure_name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 [execution_time] [time](0) NULL,
 [execute_every_min] [int] NULL,
 [last_execution] [datetime] NULL,
 [next_execution] [datetime] NULL,
 [vytvoril] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [popis_procedury] [varchar](200) NULL,
 [spusteno] [int] NULL,
 [execution_day] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [smer_prenosu_dat] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [typ] [varchar](10) NOT NULL)

Comment: I'd verify that your service program isn't running twice. You can do this by logging when your service starts in OnStart and make sure it's only firing once. If that's the case, check out [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88d9e930-cf71-4a79-bea6-59a641ae4576/c-windows-service-running-twice?forum=csharpgeneral) article to fix.  It could also error out, stop and then start itself again. Also, it doesn't look like you're inserting any records from your program, just updating.  What is doing the insert? That's the only way to add records to a table.

Comment: Are you sure? WS runs every 10 seconds. WS is similar to database jobs. It calls and executes procedures according times in table jobs. I think it is problem in WS C#. Duplicate rows have different sequence, first rows have 46303191 - 46303199 and their duplicates have from same sequence 46303202-46303212.

Comment: No, I'm not sure, just trying to help.  There are occasions where Windows Services can run twice unintentionally. Also, your timer is set to 5000 milliseconds or 5 seconds.  If you're getting records inserted into your table, something must be inserting them. Your Windows Service program only has updates from what I can see.  You execute a stored procedure at the end which I'm assuming includes an insert statement.  Also, is 5 seconds enough time to execute your SELECT statement, then execute 4 UPDATES and a stored procedure n number of times in your loop?

Comment: For 10 seconds, you should have `myTimer = new Timer(10000);` Your timer may fire a second time before the first event has time to finish. You're executing at least 5 SQL statements in your timer... 4 of them in a loop n number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments, it was helpfull. C# service fired procedure twice times. So I added second control directly into service (first check in procedure was not enough). Solution:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//using System.
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using log4net;

namespace WindowsService
{
class WindowsService : ServiceBase
{
    Timer myTimer;
    bool _smyckaBezi;
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    public WindowsService()
    {
        this.ServiceName = "Windows Service Jobs";
        this.EventLog.Log = "Application";

        // These Flags set whether or not to handle that specific
        //  type of event. Set to true if you need it, false otherwise.
        this.CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
        this.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
        this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
        this.CanShutdown = true;
        this.CanStop = true;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "/console")
        {
            WindowsService ws = new WindowsService();
            ws.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue);
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new WindowsService());
        }
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
        myTimer = new Timer(10000);                                // Sets a 10 second interval
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);// Specifies The Event Handler
        myTimer.Enabled = true;                                    // Enables the control
        myTimer.AutoReset = true;                                  // makes it repeat
        myTimer.Start();
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        //base.OnStart(args);
        myTimer = new Timer(10000);                                // Sets a 10 second interval
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);// Specifies The Event Handler
        myTimer.Enabled = true;                                    // Enables the control
        myTimer.AutoReset = true;                                  // makes it repeat
        myTimer.Start();            
    }

    protected void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (LogEx le = new LogEx(log))
        {
            if (_smyckaBezi) return;
            _smyckaBezi = true;

            SqlConnection conn = null;
            string output = null;
            List<string> list = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                Config config = new Config();
                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
                conn = new SqlConnection(cs);

                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 procedure_name AS [procedure_name] FROM dbo.jobs_crm WHERE ISNULL(spusteno_WS,0)=0 AND datediff(minute, next_execution, getdate())>=0 AND upper(procedure_name) IN (SELECT upper(s.name)+'.'+upper(o.name) FROM sys.objects o JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id=s.schema_id WHERE o.type='P') ORDER BY next_execution";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                // execute the command that returns a SqlDataReader
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                // display the results
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    output = reader["procedure_name"].ToString();
                    list.Add(output);
                }
                reader.Close();

                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
                {
                    string pname = list[i];

                    try
                    {
                    string sql = "UPDATE dbo.jobs_crm SET spusteno_WS=1, last_execution = getdate(), next_execution = convert(datetime,CAST(getdate()+1 AS DATE)) + CAST(execution_time AS DATETIME) WHERE execution_time is not null AND procedure_name= '" + pname + "';";
                    SqlCommand cmdu = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmdu.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    string sql2 = "UPDATE dbo.jobs_crm SET spusteno_WS=1, last_execution = getdate(), next_execution = dateadd(minute, execute_every_min,getdate()) WHERE execute_every_min is not null AND procedure_name= '" + pname + "';";
                    SqlCommand cmdu2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, conn);
                    cmdu2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    _smyckaBezi = false;
                    
                        //execute procedure
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(list[i], conn);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(pname + " > " + ex.Message + (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : ""));
                        //le.Exception(ex);
                        le.Error(pname + " > " + ex.Message + (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : ""));
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        string sql3 = "UPDATE dbo.jobs_crm SET spusteno_WS=0 WHERE procedure_name= '" + pname + "';";
                        SqlCommand cmdu3 = new SqlCommand(sql3, conn);
                        cmdu3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)// catch (InvalidCastException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : ""));
                le.Error("Obecná chyba > " + ex.Message + (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : ""));
                //writeToLogFileService(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    _smyckaBezi = false;
                } } } } 



public static void writeToLogFileService(string logMessage)
    {
string str_LogMessage = string.Empty;
string str_LogFile = "d:\\temp\\log_jobs_test_crm.txt";
StreamWriter swLog;
        
str_LogMessage = string.Format("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, logMessage);

if (!File.Exists(str_LogFile))
{
    swLog = new StreamWriter(str_LogFile);
}
else
{
    swLog = File.AppendText(str_LogFile);
}
swLog.WriteLine(str_LogMessage);
swLog.WriteLine();

swLog.Close();
}

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }
    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
    }

    protected override void OnContinue()
    {
        base.OnContinue();
    }

    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {
        base.OnShutdown();
    }

    protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
    {

        base.OnCustomCommand(command);
    }
    protected override bool OnPowerEvent(PowerBroadcastStatus powerStatus)
    {
        return base.OnPowerEvent(powerStatus);
    }

    protected override void OnSessionChange(
              SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
    {
        base.OnSessionChange(changeDescription);
    }
}
}
```